# ReactJS Axios It doesn't let me assign array as property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jsx, destructuring

I have a React component in which I perform an get through axes to an api rest Json.

**Attached component code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import CardsGrid from "../Pages/CardsGrid";

class Axios_cards extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {
            courses : []
        }      
    }
//                              FIX ME

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/jee4nc/myjsonserver/lista')
        .then(response => this.setState({
                courses: response.data

        }))
    }
    render() {

        const { courses } = this.state
        return <div>
            {console.log(courses)}
        </div>
    }
}

export default Axios_cards;
```

To verify that if you receive the array, I put the console.log. And I can see that if ARRAY receives me :
[image]

The problem appears when I want to assign the array to another component via props :

```
render() {

        const { courses } = this.state
        return <CardsGrid courses= {courses} />
    }
}
```

Attached component code who receives the props :

```
import React from 'react';
import Cards from "../Molecules/Cards"

const CardsGrid = ({courses}) => (
    //FIX ME

    <div>
        {console.log(courses)}
    </div>
)

export default CardsGrid;
```

The console.log inside CardsGrid returns this to me : "undefined"
[image]

**Why does the CardsGrid component not recognize the Array that is assigned through props?**

Comment: You dint import Axios_cards

Comment: Also, you don't have to use `console.log` inside JSX. You can log before the `return` statement.

Comment: Could it be the space between `=` and `{courses}` in your JSX?  `return <CardsGrid courses={courses} />`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with how you are performing destructuring.

If you want each item to be prop in `CardsGrid`, I'd recommend using `.map` with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). The reason is that you have an array of objects, and you probably want each array's individual keys to become props for each card (although your code doesn't show much of how this should render):

```
render() {
   // destructure all the courses from the state obj
   const { courses } = this.state
   return (
     // use fragments to offset your JSX return and eliminate useless <div>
     <>
       // Loop over your courses array with .map
       courses.map( (course) => {
         // ...course will spread each key into CardsGrid as a prop
         // each key's value will automatically be assigned to the prop
         <CardsGrid ...course />
       })
     </>
   )
}
```